# Loop a Map Type after call an async method

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, widget

i have this method inside a class

```
Map<String, String> value = {};
bool isReady = false;


void getData() async {
    try {
        Map<String, String> data = await CustomerData().getService(selectedService);
        isReady = true;
        setState(() {
            value = data;
        });
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

i'd like to loop the results inside a widget so:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Customer'),
        ),
        body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
                value.forEach((key, value) { 
                    Text('$key: $value'),
                 })  
            ],
        ),
    );
}
```

the only solution that i found is this but i don't like it

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Customer'),
        ),
        body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
                Text(isReady ? 'Service: value["deliver"]' : '?'),
                Text(isReady ? 'Status: value["status"]' : '?'),
                Text(isReady ? 'Note: value["note"]' : '?'),
            ],
        ),
    );
}
```

is possible loop a Map type that comes from a method async inside a Widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    FutureBuilder(
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.hasData) {
           return Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children: snapshot.data!.entries
                         .map((e) => Text(' ${e.key} : ${e.value} '))
                         .toList(),
           );
         }
         return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
   },
   future: data(),
)


Future<Map<String, dynamic>> data() => Future.value({'name': 'John', 'age': 20, 'height': 5.6});
```

Comment: thanks for answer but @haris has delete his comment.... inside a futurebuilder how can use my map type?                                                                                            
   `Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<Map<String, String>>(
        future: value, // here there is an error The argument type 'Map<String, String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Map<String, String>>'
      ),
    ),`

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: value.entries.map((e) => Text('${e.key}: ${e.value}')).toList(),
),
```